# How to change/bypass 'accounts-per-user' limit on service account

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm trying to add a service account to multiple accounts within GA4 but got hit with the 'accounts-per-user' which is preventing me from adding it to all the accounts that my app needs access to. Is there a way to change this number? and if not, is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: Hello,
It seems there no way to change.
But, you can try to add new Google accounts and use one by 100 next users
You need to add save relation between account - users by you side

Comment: @Dmytro you're correct, there is no way to change this. I used the Discovery API for GA4 instead of the python package which allowed me to use a standard Google user account for authentication (They don't have this limit).

Comment: what is the Discovery API for GA4? Could you p[lease send to me link to Discovery API documentation?..

Comment: @Dmytro 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-installed.md#calling-google-apis

and I used https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.tools.html to create a flow object for authorization.